# Removing duplicate results CASE - UNION SELECT - Mysql

Tags: mysql, case, union

I have a problem with duplicate results, I have a big query.

I'm trying to make a query where a product type shows different amounts in a week, the problem I'm having is that a product is duplicated when it should appear both days in the same record, as I show below someone could help me, I'm starting to drive me crazy.

```
SELECT formatopeso.tipo_formato,
    CASE
        when dia = '1'
        then sumatotal
        else ''
    END as Lunes,
    CASE
        when dia = '2'
        then sumatotal
        else ''
    END as Martes,
    CASE
        when dia = '3'
        then sumatotal
        else ''
    END as Miércoles,
    CASE
        when dia = '4'
        then sumatotal
        else ''
    END as Jueves,
    CASE
        when dia = '5'
        then sumatotal
        else ''
    END as Viernes,
    CASE
        when dia = '6'
        then sumatotal
        else ''
    END as Sábado
FROM (
   select '1' AS dia, pedidos.fecha_entrega, id_formatopeso, sum(pedidos.unidades) as sumatotal
   from pedidos
   where yearweek(fecha_entrega,1) = yearweek(now()) and weekday(fecha_entrega)= 0
UNION
   select '2' as dia, pedidos.fecha_entrega, id_formatopeso, sum(pedidos.unidades) as sumatotal
   from pedidos
   where yearweek(fecha_entrega,1) = yearweek(now()) and weekday(fecha_entrega)= 1
UNION
   select '3' as dia, pedidos.fecha_entrega, id_formatopeso, sum(pedidos.unidades) as sumatotal
   from pedidos
   where yearweek(fecha_entrega,1) = yearweek(now()) and weekday(fecha_entrega)= 2
UNION
   select '4' as dia, pedidos.fecha_entrega, id_formatopeso, sum(pedidos.unidades) as sumatotal
   from pedidos
   where yearweek(fecha_entrega,1) = yearweek(now()) and weekday(fecha_entrega)= 3
UNION
   select '5' as dia, pedidos.fecha_entrega, id_formatopeso, sum(pedidos.unidades) as sumatotal
   from pedidos
   where yearweek(fecha_entrega,1) = yearweek(now()) and weekday(fecha_entrega)= 4
UNION
   select '6' as dia, pedidos.fecha_entrega, id_formatopeso, sum(pedidos.unidades) as sumatotal
   from pedidos
   where yearweek(fecha_entrega,1) = yearweek(now()) and weekday(fecha_entrega)= 5)
pedidos INNER JOIN formatopeso 
ON     formatopeso.id_formatopeso = pedidos.id_formatopeso
GROUP BY pedidos.id_formatopeso, fecha_entrega;
```

I have this result:

```
+--------------+-------+--------+-----------+--------+---------+--------+
| tipo_formato | Lunes | Martes | Miércoles | Jueves | Viernes | Sábado |
+--------------+-------+--------+-----------+--------+---------+--------+
| 22Ø 180gr    |       | 450    |           |        |         |        |
| 22Ø 180gr    |       |        | 100       |        |         |        |
| 27Ø 270gr    |       |        |           | 200    |         |        |
| 27Ø 270gr    |       |        |           |        | 300     |        |
+--------------+-------+--------+-----------+--------+---------+--------+
```

I need to have a result like this:

```
+--------------+-------+--------+-----------+--------+---------+--------+
| tipo_formato | Lunes | Martes | Miércoles | Jueves | Viernes | Sábado |
+--------------+-------+--------+-----------+--------+---------+--------+
| 22Ø 180gr    |       | 450    |  100      |        |         |        |
| 27Ø 270gr    |       |        |           |  200   | 300     |        |
+--------------+-------+--------+-----------+--------+---------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by `tipo_formato`, and sum up the count for each day of the week for a given `tipo_formato` value.

Your current query also has some added complexity that is not really necessary. You could get rid of the sub-query, and just change the `CASE` statements to switch on `weekday(pedidos.fecha_entrega)`.

I also suggest you enable the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` sql_mode to avoid problems with the `SELECT` clause not matching the `GROUP BY` clause. You an read more about that [here](http://mechanics.flite.com/blog/2013/02/12/why-i-use-only-full-group-by/).

I'm not sure how large your table is, but you can also improve on the performance of `yearweek(pedidos.fecha_entrega,1) = yearweek(now())` by indexing the `pedidos.fecha_entrega` column and rewriting the query to avoid wrapping `pedidos.fecha_entrega` in a function call. That's not really what you
re asking about, so I won't touch that part of the query, but it's worth thinking about if the table will be at all large.

This query should work for you:

```
SELECT formatopeso.tipo_formato,
      SUM(CASE
          when weekday(pedidos.fecha_entrega)= 0
          then pedidos.unidades
          else NULL
      END) as Lunes,
      SUM(CASE
          when weekday(pedidos.fecha_entrega)= 1
          then pedidos.unidades
          else NULL
      END) as Martes,
      SUM(CASE
          when weekday(pedidos.fecha_entrega)= 2
          then pedidos.unidades
          else NULL
      END) as Miércoles,
      SUM(CASE
          when weekday(pedidos.fecha_entrega)= 3
          then pedidos.unidades
          else NULL
      END) as Jueves,
      SUM(CASE
          when weekday(pedidos.fecha_entrega)= 4
          then pedidos.unidades
          else NULL
      END) as Viernes,
      SUM(CASE
          when weekday(pedidos.fecha_entrega)= 5
          then pedidos.unidades
          else NULL
      END) as Sábado
  FROM  pedidos
   INNER JOIN formatopeso
  ON     formatopeso.id_formatopeso = pedidos.id_formatopeso
  where yearweek(pedidos.fecha_entrega,1) = yearweek(now()) 
  GROUP BY formatopeso.tipo_formato
```

Comment: Thank so very much Ike Walker, your help has been really useful and not only that, but it has greatly reduced the code, optimized and easier to understand, it is a pleasure to receive such help.

I have verified the code and it works perfectly.